# I'll win you no prizes - who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'll win you no prizes, Nobel-worthy I'm not
But when you're lost for words, I can help quite a lot
And sometimes, if you're askin', I'm the best hope you've got
To signal your intentions to far away spots

So loosen up, think sideways, you know it's okay
Make a symbolic gesture and try me today
Leave a mark, add a dash of good taste, and employ me
But please don't overdo it, so all could enjoy me

**Who am I?**

Comment: A dictionary? Or a thesaurus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, in fact, you're:

> An emoticon.

I'll win you no prizes, Nobel-worthy I'm not

> A lot of authorities look down on emoticons.

But when you're lost for words, I can help quite a lot

> Emoticons fill in the blanks and can indicate humor, irony and sympathy.

And sometimes, if you're askin', I'm the best hope you've got

> Or sometimes a big-eyed emoticon will get someone to help you out when they are reluctant to do so. From OP: "askin'" is a play on "ascii'ing"

To signal your intentions to far away spots

> Often used in chat rooms

So loosen up, think sideways, you know it's okay
Make a symbolic gesture and try me today

> These would be typographical emoticons ;)

Leave a mark, add a dash of good taste, and employ me

> Marks and dashes are used to make emoticons

But please don't overdo it, so all could enjoy me

> Too many emoticons can become annoying and obscure the message.

Comment: Perhaps it's emoticons? "To signal your intentions to far away spots" — they are often used in social media to msg across the world. And it fits the other clues.

Comment: @QuestionAsker That sounds right. Good thought. Put it in an answer.

Comment: I'm afraid the credit doesn't go to me. You did most of the work :) — You should edit your answer

Comment: @QuestionAsker There we go. I actually had most of it written out but couldn't bear to overwrite my original answer.

Comment: you missed a small wordplay on line 3: "askin'" <--> "ASCII-ing".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are

> A hyphen.

I haven't worked out all the clues, though.

> No prizes could be a reference to the hyphenated [no-prize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_No-Prize). Lost for words means replacing the end of a sentence with a hyphen. "To signal your intentions" refers to dashes being used in morse code. "Think sideways" means it's a sideways line. "A symbolic gesture" means it's a symbol. "Leave a mark, add a dash" is pretty obvious. "Please don't over do it" could be a reference to the perpetual holy wars over how many dashes you need in a row in various circumstances.

Comment: Nice answer, but that's not it.